# JQuery search limited to Angular component's DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I would like to use JQuery inside my Angular components for DOM manipulation, but I would like to limit JQuery searches to the component's markup it's used in.

I'm trying using Shadow DOM, so I have this component:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.less'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleSidebar(): void {
    $('.main-sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    $('.content-wrapper').toggleClass('expanded');
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <button type="button" id="sidebar-collapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" (click)='toggleSidebar()'>
            <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
        </button>          
    </nav>
  </header>

  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <section class="sidebar">
      Sidebar
    </section>
  </aside>

  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content">
      Content
    </section>
  </div>

</div>
```

If I remove the `encapsulation` configuration, it works, but if I leave it in place, JQuery can't find the elements searched. I would like to know how can I make JQuery find those elements. Is there any other way of limiting JQuery searches apart from using Shadow DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do menu toggling with jQuery?
It is not good practice to use it with Angular application. Let Angular do it.

You can do it with `host binding`

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar">
   <button type="button" id="sidebar-collapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" 
    (click)='toggleSidebar()'>
      <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
   </button> 
</nav>

<aside class="main-sidebar" [ngClass]="{'menu_open': menuOpen}">
   <section class="sidebar">
     Sidebar
   </section>
 </aside>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
   // set it closed by default
   @HostBinding('class.menu_open') public menuOpen = false;
   ....

   toggleSidebar() {
      this.menuOpen = !this.menuOpen;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because of the idea of using the `HostBinding` decorator, but it's not the answer I'm looking for. I'm sure that sooner or later, I will find a situation where JQuery will come handy to do something inside a component (or my boss will think it).